# Discrete time-invariant MIMO systems with a multidimensional state

Tags: linear-algebra, convolution, signal-processing, control-theory, linear-control

Consider discrete time-invariant MIMO systems with a multidimensional hidden state (or simply state) as the recursive system

$$
h_{t+1}=Ah_{t}+Bx_t+\eta_t
$$
$$
y_t=Ch_t+Dx_t+\xi_t
$$

Where $h_t$ is the hidden state, $x_t$ is the input, $y_t$ is the output, and $\eta_t,\xi_t$ are noise vectors.

Show that if for $t \leq 0$ $x_t,\eta_t,\xi_t$ be the zero vectors of appropriate dimension, then the output at time $t$ is as follows

$$
y_t = \sum_{i=1}^{t-1}CA^i(Bx_{t-i}+\eta_{t-i})+CA^th_0+Dx_t+\xi_t
$$

For more information, please refer to the following paper by Elad Hazan page 3:

[Learning Linear Dynamical Systems via Spectral Filtering](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/7247-learning-linear-dynamical-systems-via-spectral-filtering.pdf)

To derive this I started by the following

$$
t=0
$$
$$
h_{1}=Ah_{0}+Bx_0+\eta_0=Ah_{0}
$$
$$
y_1=Ch_1+Dx_1+\xi_1=C(Ah_{0})+Dx_1+\xi_1=CAh_{0}+Dx_1+\xi_1
$$

which is consistence with 
$$
y_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{1-1}CA^i(Bx_{1-i}+\eta_{1-i})+CA^1h_0+Dx_1+\xi_1=CAh_{0}+Dx_1+\xi_1
$$

$$
t=1
$$
$$
h_{2}=Ah_{1}+Bx_1+\eta_1=A(Ah_{0})+Bx_1+\eta_1=A^2h_{0}+Bx_1+\eta_1
$$
$$
y_2=Ch_2+Dx_2+\xi_2=C(A^2h_{0}+Bx_1+\eta_1)+Dx_2+\xi_2
$$
$$
y_2=CA^2h_{0}+CBx_1+C\eta_1+Dx_2+\xi_2
$$

which is not consistence with 
$$
y_2 = \sum_{i=1}^{2-1}CA^i(Bx_{2-i}+\eta_{2-i})+CA^2h_0+Dx_2+\xi_2=CABx_1+\eta_1+CA^2h_0+Dx_2+\xi_2
$$

Could you please tell me why I have extra $A$ when I use the recursive formulas but the paper's equality does not have it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the paper might have a typo with the indexing in the equation, namely it should be

$$
y_t = C\,A^t h_0 + D\,x_t + \xi_t + \sum_{i=0}^{t-1} C\,A^i (B\,x_{t-i-1} + \eta_{t-i-1}), \tag{1}
$$

which gives

\begin{align}
y_0 &= C\,h_0 + D\,x_0 + \xi_0, \\
y_1 &= C\,A\,h_0 + D\,x_1 + \xi_1 + C(B\,x_0 + \eta_0), \\
y_2 &= C\,A^2\,h_0 + D\,x_2 + \xi_2 + C(B\,x_1 + \eta_1) + C\,A(B\,x_0 + \eta_0).
\end{align}

Equation $(1)$ can also be rewritten such that it is easier to exclude the contribution of $x_0$ and $\eta_0$ be reversing the order of the summation

$$
y_t = C\,A^t h_0 + D\,x_t + \xi_t + \sum_{i=0}^{t-1} C\,A^{t-i-1} (B\,x_i + \eta_i), \tag{2}
$$

which also agrees with section 4.1.3 of [these notes](http://www.dcsc.tudelft.nl/~sc4060/transp/discreteNOTES.pdf). In your case you could use

$$
y_t = C\,A^t h_0 + D\,x_t + \xi_t + \sum_{i=1}^{t-1} C\,A^{t-i-1} (B\,x_i + \eta_i). \tag{3}
$$

Comment: @ Kwin: I prefer (1). Also if we change indices of the sum from $i=1$ to $t$, the new sum would be $$
y_t = C\,A^t h_0 + D\,x_t + \xi_t + \sum_{i=1}^{t} C\,A^{i-1} (B\,x_{t-i} + \eta_{t-i})
$$

Comment: @Saeed That would work as well.

Comment: Can you help to understand how come $\hat{y}_t-y_{t-1}$ at page 7 of the paper is equal to what the writer claims?

Comment: @Saeed It states that the full derivation can be found in Appendix C, but I do not see an Appendix at all in that paper. It also seems to be related to state observers (output prediction), which can be answered  quickly and that would be better suited as a new question.

Comment: The full paper can be found here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.00946.pdf. However, it has nothing to do with the first line of formula (4) in the paper. I am wondering whether the author uses which part to come up with $\hat{y}_t-y_{t-1}$?